# Contractions of hyper-cubes and how many of them

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

*Contraction* here means edge contraction with loop and multiple edges removed. For instant, there are four contractions (up to isomorphism) of the square ($Q_2$), namely a i) a single vertex, ii) an edge (the path of length 1), iii) a triangle and iv) the square itself. For example, the edge ($P_1$) can be obtained by contracting a pair of edges of the original square that share a vertex or a pair of edges that share no vertices then remove multiple edges down to one. If we count the number of copies of each type then there are 1 copy of a single vertex, 1 copy of the square itself, 4 copies of the triangle and 6 copies of the edge.

So what do we know about the answers to these questions for hypercubes (even just for $Q_3$) in general besides just to count them by a program? My hope (and believe) is that there must be some theoretical results on this issue.

Comment: In the hope of renewing some interest on this topic, we found and believe the answer for $Q_3$ to be 958.